# Sticky footer and footer color not changing

Tags: html, css, background-color, sticky-footer

I am having a problem getting my footer to stay at the bottom I have made it position: fixed; but it will still come up if the content changes. Also, i can't get the background-color to change. Is there something wrong with my code that I am just not seeing?

HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <span class="left text-muted">content </span>
    <span class="right">
    Content
    </span>  
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.footer {
height: 60px;
background-color: #939598;
position: fixed;
}

.left {
float:left;
align: left;
}

.right {
float:right;
}
```

Comment: just change your id into class or vice versa, right now you assigned your footer as an id and used it as class in your css and that's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong selector.

Its supposed to be the id based selector `#footer` and not the class based `.footer`.

```css
#footer {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #939598;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <span class="left text-muted">content </span>
    <span class="right">
   footer  Content
    </span> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked great!